# AWS Glue cryptic: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o82.parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm using AWS Glue to move concat some smaller parquet files to larger ones with a very simple pyspark script. However, I keep getting the following error and it very cryptic. clearly it has to do with writing some file out, but I have no idea if its corrupt data or resources of what. Has any had an error like this while using AWS Glue or spark in general?

```
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1522879912040_0003/container_1522879912040_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 644, in parquet
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1522879912040_0003/container_1522879912040_0003_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1522879912040_0003/container_1522879912040_0003_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1522879912040_0003/container_1522879912040_0003_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o82.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:494)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 63 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 63.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 986, ip-172-31-31-4.ec2.internal, executor 34): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 34 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1522879912040_0003_01_003509 on host: ip-172-31-31-4.ec2.internal. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
... 31 more
```

Comment: The Error message doesn't have much information. Can you please provide some code in the glue notebook that you have used